# Powershell | How to calculate current date -5 days to Epoch time?

Tags: powershell, epoch

So I'm trying to write a script to get the current date and subtrace 5 days from it. Then change that date to Epoch time. However it's not really working out properly. I've currently been unable to subtract the 5 days from it, this is currently my script:

```
$unixTime = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date -UFormat %s))
return $unixTime
```

I've also tried the following:

```
$unixTime = [int][double]::Parse(((Get-Date).AddDays(-5) -UFormat %s)))
return $unixTime
```

And also :

```
$unixTime = [int][double]::Parse((Get-Date) -UFormat %s).AddDays(-5))
return $unixTime
```

But so far I haven't been able to make it work. Does anyone know what I have to change about this calculation to make it work? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be what you're after?

```
Get-Date $((Get-Date).AddDays(-5)) -UFormat +%s
```

Comment: Yes this is what I've been looking for! However I just noticed the time is set in GMT and my timezone is CEST. Do you happen to know how to make up for this 2 hour difference?

Comment: Ah, apologies! I've just removed the `.ToUniversalTime()` reference, and simplified it a little. Hopefully this is it :) Essentially, pass a date object with 5 days subtracted, to `Get-Date` and specify the format to be `+%s`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a new [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=netframework-4.6.1) object instead.

```
[System.DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddDays(-5).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()
```